# Programmatically cancel/stop StoreKit request

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to create my own timeout for StoreKit, as it doesn't always load products quickly or at all (today was extremely poor for some reason). I can't seem to find a method to stop a currently in progress SKRequest and or SKProductsRequest, as there is only a `start` method.

Could anyone help point me in the right direction so that I can make something such as a 15 second max timeout for requesting the products, and purchasing/restoring the products?

I'd greatly appreciate it!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `SKRequest` class has a `cancel` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKRequest/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKRequest), so you can call that.

Comment: I just noticed that, woops!